# Express the function $\displaystyle{\frac{(z+2)^2}{z^2-1}}$ as a series in the domain $1<|z|<2$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Using partial fractions, for $1<|z|<2$, it results
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{(z+2)^2}{z^2-1} &=& 1+\frac{9/2}{z-1}-\frac{1/2}{z+1}\\&=& 1+\frac{9}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}\right)-\frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}\right)\\&=& 1+\frac{9}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n}-\frac{1}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^{-n}\\&=& 1+\frac{9}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^{-n-1}.\qquad (\clubsuit)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if $ n $ is even, then $ (- 1)^n=1$. Later
$$ \frac{9}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{-n-1} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1 )^nz^{- n-1} = 4\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{- n-1}. $$
But, if $ n $ is odd, then $ (- 1)^n = -1 $. So
$$\frac{9}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{- n-1} -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1 )^nz^{- n-1} = 5\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{- n-1}. $$
For the above reasons, and noting that if $ n $ is odd, then $ -n-1 $ is even, and if $ n $ is even, then $ -n-1 $ is odd; from $ (\clubsuit) $ you have to
$$\frac{(z+2)^2}{z^2-1}=1+4\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{-2m-1}+5\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{-2m}=1+\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{-2m}\left(4z^{-1}+5\right).$$

This is my idea, ***but in the end I notice that this one is not in the form of a Laurent serial expansion in $1<|z|<2$.***

***Now my question point to point is, can I express the given function as a Laurent series in the indicated domain?***

Comment: Why not just directly expand without decomposition as $$\frac{(1+2z^{-1})^2}{1-z^{-2}}=(1+2z^{-1})^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-2k}?$$

Comment: What's the point of imposing that $|z|<2$? There is no need for that assumption.

Comment: Use the fact that $$ \frac{(z+2)^2}{z^2-1}=\frac{\left((z+2)/z\right)^2}{(z^2-1)/z^2}=\frac{\left(1+2/z\right)^2}{1-1/z^2}=\left(1+2z^{-1}\right)^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-2n}$$ it's a good trick. Thanks!!